# Using Tkinter in python can we highLight given string or text in LibreOffice , Gedit or in FireFox?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gnome

I am trying to highlight particular line or text in LibreOffice, So for that can I use Tkinter in python for highlighting particular Line in LibreOffice , or in Gedit . For Highlighting text of LibreOffice what can I do? Please guide me.

Comment: Or is there any tool or library available in python for highlighting text?

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically manipulating another program's canvas is only possible if that program exposes an API for that. You would be targeting each specific API, not Tkinter.

<del>As far as I know, none of the programs you discuss have Python bindings for anything like this. All of them have a plugin architecture, though, so it's not impossible, but you would have to be very lucky to find something beginner-friendly.</del>

**Update:** LibreOffice does, in fact, have Python support: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python_as_a_macro_language -- see also http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/examples.html#python_examples which has a Python example quite distinct from yours. There is a regex highlighting example for LibreOffice Basic which should be useful for showing you the names of the SDK functions you need.

Comment: You can also use python and selenium to do this in firefox. Alternatively use pyxpcom. on a side note you can edit the canvas of other apps the results are a bit unexpected if you dont use a api. But it can be done.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't particularly want to bring up guerrilla hacking as an answer but if you know what you are doing, anything can be monkey-patched. +1 for the Firefox pointers.

Answer (score 0):

[Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) is primarily a GUI (graphical user interface) tool, so while you could use it to create the GUI for a program that would highlight text, it probably isn't really what you're looking for.

It probably would help if you were a little more specific with what exactly you needed to do. Such as: are you trying to highlight a specific line every time it appears in a file (usually the find function in a complex word processor can do this see [here](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/3/35/WG40-WriterGuideLO.pdf), page 70), are you trying to search closed files and highlight a specific line in a closed file (probably more along the lines of something Python would be useful for), or what have you. As it is your question is a little vague.

Comment: HI , I am trying to read first line of paraghraph from libreOffice , Gedit or from fireFox , in python and highLight it . so how to highLight means in liberOffice how we highLight Line?

Comment: LibreOffice and Gedit I'm not as sure about, but I'd imagine once you read the file with the appropriate python library, you search for text between the new paragraph character and the new line symbol (or period if you mean line as in sentence.) For firefox (or any web browser) you'd probably want to use a HTML parser.